# Unknown Xcode Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

I keep getting this error but I have no idea where it's coming from.

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

**How do I fix this?**

Here's the code from WebView.m

```
 #import "WebViewController1.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
```

Here's the code from WebViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done one of two things wrong here.

You either mistakenly imported `ViewController.m` (instead of `ViewController.h`) into `WebView.m`. Or your `WebView.h` and `.m` mistakenly declare the `ViewController` class instead of the `WebView` class.

Based on the comments and the updated question it seems to be latter problem.

Both `ViewController.h/.m` and `WebView.m/WebViewController.h` declare the class `ViewController`.

1. You really need to give your .h and .m files the same name. I would suggest renaming `WebView.m` to `WebViewController.m`. It makes things a lot clearer if the .h and .m for a class are the same and have the same name as the class.
2. Fix `WebViewController.h` so you declare `WebViewController` instead of `ViewController`:

   ```
   @imterface WebViewController : UIViewController
   ```
3. Fix `WebViewController.m` (the former `WebView.m` so you define `WebViewController` instead of `ViewController`.

   ```
   #import "WebViewController.h"

   @interface WebViewController ()

   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;

   @end

   @implementation WebViewController
   ```

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: If you are importing `ViewController.m`, fix the import statement to import `ViewController.h`. If your `WebView.h` and `.m` declare `ViewController` instead of `WebView`, fix your `@interface` and `@implementation` lines to declare `WebView`.

Comment: Instead of ViewController, I put "UIwebView" but then I received 6 different errors. Here's what my .m file looks like (which UIwebView on @implementation and @interface) - http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOUxz.png

Comment: You're not doing what I stated. Your `ViewController.m` and `ViewController.h` files are fine (most likely). You need to edit your `WebView.h` and `WebView.m` files. This has nothing to do with references to `UIWebView`. If you are still having issues, update your question with your `WebView.h` file and the top portion of your `WebView.m` file (from the 1st learn just just a few lines beyond the `@implementation` line).

Comment: I added the code from the webview.m and the viewcontroller.h to my question

Comment: I clearly stated to add `WebView.h` and `WebView.m`.

Comment: There is no WebView.h only WebView.m and WebViewController.h

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have duplicate class names (ViewController) one in WebView.m and one in ViewController.m

Comment: So which one do I remove?

Comment: Don't remove, just rename one of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported ViewController.h in your WebView.h and at the same time for your need , might have imported WebView.h in your ViewController.h 
The compiler will find the same ViewController imported two times , first in your WebView.h and Second is your actual ViewController.h

This is because the duplicate entries are found.

Please do not import the ViewController.h in your WebView.h while you are importing WebView.h in your ViewController.h

Comment: Simply importing the two .h files wouldn't cause a linker error for duplicate symbols. If anything, you might get a compiler error.